# Why does the onclick execute without clicking on it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

**problem**: the page executes the javascript `onclick` propertise before get clicked.
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="demo">Hello World!</h1>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.onclick = alert("clicked");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**solution**: when I change the line `x.onclick = alert("clicked");`
to 
`x.onclick = function() {alert("clicked")};`
It works.
I want to understand the reason behind this behavior of `onclick`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that behaviour is, that you simply make a function call and when the JavaScript interpreter comes to that line it will be directly executed. You need to implement a reference to a function or a function definition itself to avoid this (as you did in your **solution**).

```
x.onclick = myMethod() // NOT working due to directly execution
x.onclick = () => myMethod() // working
x.onclick = myMethod // working
x.onclick = function() { myMethod() } // working
```

Answer (score 0):

I f you write the code this way also works same

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var x; 
x.onclick = alert("clicked");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

SO your code not understand where you try to send this alert so automatically display
so that's not a good way If you try to display alert when clicked on text then do this method

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="demo" >Hello world!</h1>
<script>

document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function(){
    alert("clicked");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```